# SortOn an m-array of objects

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, so I have an m-array (Or an array of arrays in actionscript as it doesn't really have m-arrays) and each array in the superarray has a number of objects created at different times in it. I want to sort the superarray by in descending order of the value of the "time" paramater of the object at index 0 in each subarray.

I've tried

```
superarray.sortOn([0].time, Array.DESCENDING);
```

and

```
superarray.sortOn("0.time", Array.DESCENDING);
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Will I just have to write my own sort function to do this? If so what's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Array.sort function passing a compare function. Something like this:

```
var superarray:Array = [
    [{time:900}, {time:715}, {time:655}],
    [{time:450}, {time:333}, {time:100}],
    [{time:999}, {time:75}, {time:30}]
    ];
var sorted:Array = superarray.sort( function(A:Array,B:Array):int {
    return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(A[0].time, B[0].time);
    });
```

Comment: Hey, this worked. I didn't know about passing a compare function. I changed it slightly to reflect my needs but this was great advice.